# sql CAST alternative in scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was looking for an alternative for a SQL query in Spark scala in specific,
My query is below :
`CAST( COLUMN as NUMERIC(18,2))`

How would i rewrite the same using spark?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may try like below

```
 dframe.col("COLUMN").cast("decimal(18,2)")
```

Comment: what if i want to subtract like .      \n `1-DF("col").divide(100)` something like this but it throws an error **Type MismatchError** . how do i solve this this is like subtracting the column which is divided by 100 with 1